# boost::graph add_vertex compilation error

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I'm trying boost::graph header library, but I still can't add verticles to my graph.

Here is how I use add_vertex function :

```
void GraphManager::addToGraph(VertexProperties node){

    //no error, but i do not need it
    vertex_t v = boost::add_vertex(graph);

    //compilation error
    vertex_t v = boost::add_vertex(node, graph);

    /*...*/
}
```

My definitions are here :

```
#ifndef GRAPH_DEFINITION_H
#define GRAPH_DEFINITION_H

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include "matchedword.h"

typedef MatchedWord* VertexProperties;

struct EdgeProperties
{
   int distance;
   EdgeProperties() : distance(0) {}
   EdgeProperties(int d) : distance(d) {}
};

struct GraphProperties {

};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
   boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
   boost::property<VertexProperties, boost::vertex_bundle_t>,
   boost::property<EdgeProperties, boost::edge_bundle_t>,
   boost::property<GraphProperties, boost::graph_bundle_t>
> Graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor edge_t;


#endif // GRAPH_DEFINITION_H
```

Any idea ?
Thanks.

> error: no matching function for call to 'add_vertex(MatchedWord*&,
>   Graph&)' candidates are: [...]
>   template typename Config::vertex_descriptor boost::add_vertex(const
>   typename Config::vertex_property_type&, boost::adj_list_impl&)
>
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> note:   'Graph {aka boost::adjacency_list, boost::property, boost::property >}' **is not derived from
>   'boost::adj_list_impl'**

I do not understand the meaning of this error output.

Comment: It's basically saying that the function you are trying to call with the parameters you put doesn't exist, but there is a version with different parameters. i.e. the function exists, but there is no version that matches the parameters you gave.

Comment: More precisely, it says that the reason is that the graph I am passing as an argument is not derived from 'boost::adj_list_impl'. However, 'boost::add_vertex(boost::adj_list_impl)' does work when passing my graph, but not 'boost::add_vertex(boost:vertex_property_type&, boost::adj_list_impl&)' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ravenspoint, you were right, I just misused bundle properties.

Here is my code, which works now :)

```
#ifndef GRAPH_DEFINITION_H
#define GRAPH_DEFINITION_H

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include "matchedword.h"

struct VertexProperties {
public :
    MatchedWord* matchedWord;
};

struct EdgeProperties
{
   int distance;
   EdgeProperties() : distance(0) {}
   EdgeProperties(int d) : distance(d) {}
};

struct GraphProperties {

};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
   boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
   VertexProperties,
   EdgeProperties,
   GraphProperties
> Graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor edge_t;


#endif // GRAPH_DEFINITION_H
```

The called function (maybe I'll rework the definition later) is:

```
void GraphManager::addToGraph(VertexProperties node){
    vertex_t v = boost::add_vertex(graph);
    graph[v].matchedWord = node.matchedWord;
}
```

Thanks for your answers all !

Comment: If you answered your own question, accept the answer. If you liked ravespoint's answer, accept that one.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to use bundled properties.

Something like this:

```
// A class to hold bundled properties for a vertex
// In this case, we have a pointer to a MatchedWord object

class vertex_props {
public:
MatchedWord * pMW;
};
```

Define a graph type with bundled properties

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
vertex_props,
...
> Graph_t;
```

Now you can add a vertex with specified bundled properties like this

```
void GraphManager::addToGraph(MatchedWord * node){
   graph[ boost::add_vertex(graph) ].pMW = node;
   ...
```

Comment: With matchedWord* bundled in VertexProperties :
boost::add_vertex(graph).matchedWord=node; does not work since add_vertex returns a vertex_descriptor. So I tried :
    vertex_t v = boost::add_vertex(graph);
    graph[v].matchedWord=node;
But it still don't work : " boost::adjency_list<...>::vertex_bundle has no member named matchedWord " !?? (it has)

Comment: Cannot be sure without seeing your code, but it sounds like you have not defined your graph type to use bundled properties.  Please post your code.